# Rails 3.1, Paperclip, Multiple file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

Anybody knows an example tutorial, how to upload multiple files (unlimited quantity) with paperclip & Rails 3.1? All examples I've seen are uploading fixed files count per one upload.

Comment: That is a very simple [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=upload+multiple+files+with+paperclip+rails#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=upload+multiple+files+with+paperclip+in+rails&pbx=1&oq=upload+multiple+files+with+paperclip+in+rails&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4809l4995l0l5187l3l3l0l0l0l2l227l405l0.1.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=cb9b5b7b3a74ed30&biw=1094&bih=974) which turns up almost 15 thousand results.

Comment: [The very first result on Google](http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads) when searching for the keywords in your title answers your question entirely.

Comment: May be my question wasn't explained exactly - I need to upload from 1 to n files per one upload, and in this tutorials attachments are limited 5.times { @article.assets.build }

Comment: Can this help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605787/uploading-multiple-files-with-paperclip/19379756#19379756

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also looking for it. I found this page:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/

There is a demo over there. It is not based on paperclip, it seems, but then I also found this one:

https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails

Which has a linked repository with an example with paperclip:

https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example

Maybe this one can get us in the right direction!

Good luck!