# paperclip uploading muliple images, renaming the name"avatar"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have installed paperclip for my ruby on rails project. But I cant upload multiple images.
I have two different fields where I want to upload images for `eg logo and picture.`

Can I change the name "avatar" to indicate the name of the field?? Is it possible?

Comment: does it work for single image upload?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading multiple files with paperclip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605787/uploading-multiple-files-with-paperclip)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

If you want to change "avatar" to "logo" using below command

```
rails g paperclip modalname logo
```

where logo is your field name.

I hope you understand and may be it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need some ideas to work with `Rails` & `Paperclip`:

---

**Paperclip**

Handles a file attachment & sends the data to your DB

**- Creates DB entries:**

```
your_definition_file_name
your_definition_content_type
your_definition_file_size
your_definition_uploaded_at
```

**- Handles Objects called `_your_definition`**

```
#app/models/attachment.rb
Class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :your_definition
end
```

Paperclip basically acts like a bridge between your db & your files -- meaning you just have to keep the object name consistent to get it to work

---

**Code**

If you have two fields (`logo` & `picture`), you'll need to declare them in your attachment model, pass their params, and add the columns in your table:

```
#app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb
def create
    @attachment = Attachment.new(attachment_params)
    @attachment.save
end

private

def attachment_params
    params.require(:attachment).permit(:logo, :picture)
end

#app/models/attachment.rb
Class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :logo
    has_attached_file :picture
end

#db/migrate
def change
     add_attachment :attachments, :logo
end

attachments
id | logo_file_name | logo_content_type | logo_file_size | logo_uploaded_at | picture_file_name | picture_content_type | picture_file_size | picture_uploaded_at | created_at | updated_at
```

---

**Recommendation**

The above code is not very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

I would recommend using a `type` attribute in your attachment model, setting the type each time you upload

This way, you can call the `attachment` as `image` or similar, uploading with the extra para of `type` each time:

```
#app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb
def create
    @attachment = Attachment.new(attachment_params)
    @attachment.save
end

private

def attachment_params
    params.require(:attachment).permit(:image, :type)
end

#app/models/attachment.rb
Class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
end

#db/migrate
def change
     add_attachment :attachments, :logo
end

attachments
id | image_file_name | image_content_type | image_file_size | image_uploaded_at | type | created_at | updated_at
```